Column receiving null value
I have a User Entity and a Role Entity. Each Role has its ROLE_ID and I would like to reference this column in the USERS table. The Column is being created normally, but the assigned value is NULL, Image to follow ->

My UserEntity is
package com.br.BookStoreAPI.models.entities;

import com.br.BookStoreAPI.models.DTOs.loginDTOs.LoginRequestDTO;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.*;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long userId;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "USER_FIRST_NAME")
    private String userFirstName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "USER_LAST_NAME")
    private String userLastName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "USER_EMAIL")
    private String userEmail;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "USER_PASSWORD")
    private String userPassword;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private RoleEntity role;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "USER_ROLES",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    )
    private Set<RoleEntity> roles;

    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    @Column(name = "MODIFICATION_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime modificationDate;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        creationDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        modificationDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

//    public boolean getRoleByName(String roleName) {
//        return roles.stream()
//                .anyMatch(role -> role.getRole().name().equals(roleName));
//    }
    
    public boolean isLoginCorrect(LoginRequestDTO loginRequestDTO, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        return passwordEncoder.matches(loginRequestDTO.password(), this.userPassword);
    }
}

My RoleEntity are
package com.br.BookStoreAPI.models.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLES")
@Getter
@Setter
public class RoleEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Long roleId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "ROLE", nullable = false)
    private RoleType role;

    public enum RoleType {
        ADMIN(1L),
        USER(2L);

        private final long roleId;

        RoleType(long roleId) {
            this.roleId = roleId;
        }

        public long getRoleId() {
            return roleId;
        }
    }
}

To create user I'm using the Postman, with this maneer:
java

{
    "userFirstName": "MatheusTeste2",
    "userLastName": "Castilho",
    "userEmail": "Matheus.castilho124@gmail.com",
    "userPassword": "senhaSegura"
}

But I have a class that set a role in UserService, Is like that:
    public UserResponseDTO create(UserRequestDTO dto) {
        var role = roleRepository.findByRoleName(RoleEntity.RoleType.USER.name());
        var userFromDb = userRepository.findByUserEmail(dto.userEmail());
        if (userFromDb.isPresent()) {
            throw new UserAlreadyExistsException("User's email " + dto.userEmail() + " is already in use. " );
        }

        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        userEntity.setUserFirstName(dto.userFirstName());
        userEntity.setUserLastName(dto.userLastName());
        userEntity.setUserEmail(dto.userEmail());
        userEntity.setUserPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(dto.userPassword()));
        userEntity.setRoles(Set.of(role));

        UserEntity result = userRepository.save(userEntity);

        return new UserResponseDTO(result);
    }

The logging after I create the new User:
2024-10-29T19:19:39.854-03:00  INFO 11020 --- [BookStoreAPI] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-10-29T19:19:39.854-03:00  INFO 11020 --- [BookStoreAPI] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-10-29T19:19:39.856-03:00  INFO 11020 --- [BookStoreAPI] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2024-10-29T19:19:40.272-03:00  INFO 11020 --- [BookStoreAPI] [nio-8080-exec-2] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
    1274800 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    2370500 nanoseconds spent preparing 4 JDBC statements;
    18114500 nanoseconds spent executing 4 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    10545200 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 2 entities and 1 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)

And I make the query using DBeaver like the follow command:
SELECT * FROM users


You forgot to ask a question.

You link UserEntity to RoleEntity with two relationships.
You describe the first relationship in code
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
private RoleEntity role;

This is a many-to-one relationship, where each user can have only one role.
At the database level, this relationship is implemented using the ROLE_ID column in the USERS table, which contains the role id from the ROLES table and is related to it by a foreign key constraint. To create this relationship, you must assign the role field of the UserEntity a reference to one RoleEntity object.
userEntity.setRoles(role);

You describe the second relationship with the code
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
  name = "USER_ROLES",
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"),
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
)
private Set<RoleEntity> roles;

This is a many-to-many relationship, where each user can have any number of any roles. At the database level, this relationship is implemented using an additional table USER_ROLES, which contains two columns. One column USER_ID contains the user id from the USERS table and is linked to the users table by a foreign key constraint. The second column ROLE_ID contains the role id from the ROLES table and is related to the roles table by a foreign key constraint. To create this relationship, you need to assign the roles field of the UserEntity a set containing references to RoleEntity objects.
This is exactly what you do in the code
userEntity.setRoles(Set.of(role));

Here Set.of(role) is a set containing a reference to a role object, so Hibernate will add one record to the USER_ROLES table, with the USER_ID column containing the id of the user whose email address is equivalent to the value returned by the dto.userEmail(), and the ROLE_ID column containing the id of the USER role.
Therefore, the ROLE_ID column is NULL because you are not assigning the role field of the UserEntity a reference to the RoleEntity. It makes sense for you to get rid of one of the relationships.
